# TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer for android/ios

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

On all platforms (except windows) `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` is a `TSimpleRWSync` that internally simply use `Tmonitor.enter` / `Tmonitor.exit` and this is quite bad because only one read access at a time. Is their any equivalent of `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` (windows version) that work on Android/iOS ?

Comment: May I ask why you need that feature?

Comment: @Olivier simple, write access are very rare compared to read access and I don't want to lock read access if no write is actually performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`TLightweightMREW`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SyncObjs.TLightweightMREW) record in `System.SyncObjs` fully implemented on all platforms as thin wrapper around native OS implementations. Introduced in 10.4.1 Sydney.

There are some things to keep in mind:

- Read access can be called recursively from same thread, but write access cannot - it will deadlock on Windows and raise exception on Posix platforms
- Read access cannot be upgraded to write access.

Comment: Note that it was introduced in 10.4.1.

Comment: Woow I didn't know about TLightweightMREW it's look wonderfull feature! As it's quite new I just hop it's not buggy (like for exemple the Tmonitor at it's beginning)

Comment: I can not find any example of TLightweightMREW and the doc is quite obscure on the good way to use it. I don't understand how to use it, seam their is no TLightweightMREW.create? How it's work ? Is it a global lock ?

Comment: It is managed record and it is automatically initialized (there is no Create and Free). You use it just like you would use any other lock. Declare lock variable where you need it and use its methods: `BeginRead`, `TryBeginRead`, `EndRead`, `BeginWrite`, `TryBeginWrite`, `EndWrite`